# How to non-recursively replace "rep" element of a list with the previous element in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to duplicate the element of a list before the "rep" element, in a NON-recursive way. For example, I have the list

```
[1,2,rep,3,4,5]
```

and I want to end up with

```
[1,2,2,3,4,5]
```

or

```
[rep,1,2,3,4,5]
```

and want

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

So far I have:

```
element_repeat_non(List,Sol):-
  findall(X,element_inner(List,X),Sol).
        
element_inner(List,X):-
  member(X,List),
  not(X==rep).
```

This, however, only ignores the `rep` element and returns a list without it, giving the desired result in the case of

```
[rep,1,2,3,4,5]
```

but not in the case of

```
[1,2,rep,3,4,5]
```

I can't figure out how I can keep the previous element so I can replace the "rep" element. If possible, I would like to avoid using a condition check(if_then_else).

Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `[rep,rep]`?

Comment: There can be a maximum of one "rep" element in the list.

Comment: "Non-recursive" really means "recursion can happen as long as I don't see it in front of me", because *append* uses recursion :-)

Comment: Is `do_funky_stuff([rep, rep], L)` supposed to result in `L = [rep]`, or failure?

Comment: @brebs Since there can only be one occurrence of "rep" in the list, this is not an issue I have to address.

Comment: There is no non-recursive solution to this problem. The only way to iterate over a list is to use recursion.

Comment: @NicholasCarey "*There is no non-recursive solution to this problem. The only way to iterate over a list is to use recursion*" - I have another attempt which doesn't iterate over a list; any recursion hiding in this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72283785/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that there can be **at most one occurrence** of the atom `rep` in the input list (as you have stated in your last comment), a possible solution is as follows:

```
% repeat_previous(+List, -NewList)

  repeat_previous([rep|L], L).
  repeat_previous(L, L) :-
      not(append(_, [rep|_], L)).
  repeat_previous(L, S) :-
      append(Xs, [Y,rep|Ys], L),
      append(Xs, [Y,Y|Ys], S).
```

Examples:

```
?- repeat_previous([1,2,3,4,5], L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ;
false.

?- repeat_previous([rep,1,2,3,4,5], L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ;
false.

?- repeat_previous([1,2,rep,3,4,5], L).
L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5] ;
false.

?- repeat_previous([1,2,3,4,5,rep], L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5] ;
false.
```

Comment: `append/3` is recursive, just sayin'. Tain't no way to iterate in Prolog  other than recursion.

Comment: @NicholasCarey Of course, all the predicates that process the elements of a list are based on some form of recursion (but according to this point of view, the problem would have no solution). So I think that the OP asks for a predicate whose DEFINITION is non-recursive (and that's what I did - the definition of `repeat_previous/2` IS non-recursive).

Answer (score 1):

Slightly bending the rules, to use DCG:

```
elem_repeat_dcg(Lst, LstRepeated) :-
    phrase(elem_repeated, Lst, LstRepeated).

% If starts with rep, then just use the remainder
elem_repeated --> [rep], !.
elem_repeated --> elem_repeating.

% Perform the repeat
elem_repeating, [Prev, Prev] --> [Prev], [rep], !.
% Loop through list
elem_repeating, [NotRep] --> [NotRep], !, elem_repeating.
% Accept end of list, if rep is not found
elem_repeating --> [].
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- elem_repeat_dcg([1,2,rep,3,4,5], LstRepeated).
LstRepeated = [1,2,2,3,4,5].

?- elem_repeat_dcg([rep,3,4,5], LstRepeated).
LstRepeated = [3,4,5].

?- elem_repeat_dcg([1,2,3,4,5], LstRepeated).
LstRepeated = [1,2,3,4,5].

?- time(elem_repeat_dcg([1,2,rep,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], LstRepeated)).
% 4 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (82% CPU, 104430 Lips)
LstRepeated = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].
```

And here is a variation of the DCG portion, with the same results:

```
% If starts with rep, then just use the remainder
elem_repeated --> [rep], !.
elem_repeated, [First] --> [First], elem_repeating(First).

% Perform the repeat
elem_repeating(E), [E] --> [rep], !.
% Loop through list
elem_repeating(_), [E] --> [E], !, elem_repeating(E).
% Accept end of list, if rep is not found
elem_repeating(_) --> [].
```

Whoever set the question is probably wanting the likes of:

```
% This is what NOT to do
elem_repeat(Lst, LstRepeated) :-
    append([Before, [rep], After], Lst),
    append([_, [RepElem]], Before),
    append([Before, [RepElem], After], LstRepeated).
```

... which **ruins performance** by not just using the **tail** of the list, after the replacement has been performed - which is what difference lists can do... and DCGs use difference lists *behind the scenes*.

Comment: Also a recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can't use recursion, can't use branching, then how about using [`scanl/4`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=scanl/4) ?

```
rep(rep, Prev, Prev).
rep(  E,    _,    E) :- dif(E, rep).

reps_plain(In, Out) :-
    scanl(rep, In, nil, [nil,X|Xs]),
    ( (X = nil,     Out = Xs)
    ; (dif(X, nil), Out = [X|Xs])).
```

scanl is built to do things like running sums, i.e. it takes the current value and the output of the previous value and calls the goal with those. Using this to carry the state with the previous value to repeat. However, for the first value scanl has no previous value to use so you need to provide one (here I've used `nil`), so the list always comes out `[nil|_]` and if you put `[rep,1,2,3]` then the list comes out `[nil,nil|_]` repeating the previous value which is the initial placeholder value; that's because this is not really what scanl is built for. Each scanl step has to output a value it can't drop an entry from the list instead. So at the end it removes either two or one `nil`.

Comment: And.... `scanl`, too, is recursive: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl/blob/25c667d54f3337ac70d744813b6563e7b7c40a0d/library/apply.pl#L347

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-recursive solution:

```
element_repeat( []         ,      []  ) .
element_repeat( [rep|Xs]   ,      Xs  ) .
element_repeat( [X,rep|Xs] , [X,X|Ys] ) .
element_repeat( [X,Y|Xs]   , [X,Y|Ys] ) :- Y \= rep, element_repeat(Xs,Ys) .
```

because TRO (tail recursion optimization) converts it into iteration.

If one were to use `append/3`, I would approach it like so:

```
element_repeat( [rep|Xs] , Xs ) :- ! .
element_repeat( Xs       , Ys ) :-
    append( Pfx, [X,rep|Sfx] , Xs ) ,
    append( Pfx,   [X,X|Sfx] , Ys ) .
```

Comment: What about your comment in my answer "*Tain't no way to iterate in Prolog other than recursion*"?

Comment: You do have a point 

Comment: The third clause in the first version of the predicate should be `element_repeat([X,rep|Xs], [X,X|Xs]).`.

Comment: Query `?- element_repeat([1,2,rep,4,5], L).` incorrectly succeeds with `L = [1, 2, 4, 5]`, for the first version of the predicate.

Comment: Query `element_repeat([1,2,3], L).` incorrectly fails for the second version of the predicate. According to OP, it should succeed with `L = [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try again: no recursion here; length as a generator has nothing to recurse over; just failure driven loop, backtracking, database updates, and eventually unification:

```
:- dynamic(rep/2).

rep([], []).

derep(In, Out) :-
    length(_, _),
    rep(TempA,TempB),
    assertz((rep([A|TempA], [A|TempB]):-dif(A,rep))),
    assertz((rep([A,rep|TempA], [A,A|TempB]))),
    rep(In, Out),
    retractall(rep(_,_)),
    assertz(rep([], [])).
```

```
?- derep([2,3,rep,4,5], X).
X = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5] ;
```